# Get Vocabulary Categories for specific document/article in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I'm new in Liferay, and I'm trying to get the Categories of a Specific Vocabulary for a document published in Liferay.
i.e.
The vocabulary is "Languages" and the Categories are : Italian, Spanish, German, English....

I've been trying to use AssetVocabularyServiceUtil and AssetCateogiresServiceUtil, but it seems that I can only get "all" the categories or vocabularies for a specific GroupID or CompanyID for example.

As there are several Documents published, I want to retrieve the Categories for "Languages" vocabulary of each.

I hope you can guide me.

******EDIT*****
to add more details, I have a faceted search that retrieves all the documents of a specific structure, so for each of them (document) I'd like to retrieve their Categories

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to fetch categories assigned to document or article?

Comment: Yep, I want to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  AssetCategoryFinderUtil.countByG_N_V(groupId, name, vocabularyId)
```

Comment: This returns an `int`. The asker wants a list of categories.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of below API method to get Categories associated with document or Article.

`List<AssetCategory> AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCategories(String classNameId, long classPK)`

Here, className would be DLFileEntry.class.getName() and classPK would be primaryKey of DLFileEntry object.

Similarly for Article Content JournalArticle.class.getName()  would be className.